# How to simplify Euclidean norm (like $x_1^2+x_2^2\to x^2$) in an expression given the assumption?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, polynomials, algebraic-manipulation, assumptions

I am trying to use `Simplify` to reduce the expression like $x_1^2+x_2^2\to x^2$. For example,

```
Simplify[x[1]^4 + 2 x[1]^2 x[2]^2 + x[2]^4, x[1]^2 + x[2]^2 == x^2]
```

I am expecting to get `x^4` (simplicity count = 3), but I only obtain `(x[1]^2 + x[2]^2)^2` (simplicity count = 11). Why doesn't `Simplify` further simplify the expression given the assumption? What is the right way to carry out the reduction in Mathematica?

Comment: A replacement rule works well here: `Simplify[x[1]^4 + 2 x[1]^2 x[2]^2 + x[2]^4] /. x[1]^2 + x[2]^2 -> x^2` returns `x^4`. Still a good point about `Simplify` though.

Answer (score 1):

As noted under "Possible Issues" in the documentation for [`Simplify`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Simplify.html), "results of simplification may depend on the names of symbols":

```
Simplify[a^4 + 2 a^2 b^2 + b^4, a^2 + b^2 == c^2]
(* c^4 *)
```

Answer (score -3):

I think that you make a mistake on the way Simplify act. It can accept an assumption --- beeing real, integer, positive, not an equation --- the distinction is subtile.

Look at this

Simplify[Subscript[x, 1]^4 + 2 Subscript[x, 1]^2 Subscript[x, 2]^2 + 
   Subscript[x, 2]^4 ] /. Subscript[x, 1]^2 + Subscript[x, 2]^2 -> x^2

It works

Comment: Try this: `Simplify[x + y, x + y == z]`